# pyqtgraph plot inside main form (qt designer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

my code plot this code inside my main form **perfectly**:

```
                self.graphics_View_widget.clear() 
                pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
                h=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                t=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                self.graphics_View_widget.plot(h, t, pen=(0,0,255))
```

it draws in the specified location without any problem

but when i want to change x axis into string objects like this:

```
                  self.graphics_View_widget.clear()  
                  h=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                  t=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
                  xDict=dict(enumerate(t))
                  xValue=list(xDict.keys())
                  self.graphics_View_widget= pg.GraphicsWindow()
                  bottomAxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
                  pp=self.graphics_View_widget.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': bottomAxis},name='h')
                  xtickts=[xDict.items()]
                  bottomAxis.setTicks(xtickts)
                  pp.plot(xValue,h)
```

now it draws this chart in a new window (instead of specified location in qt designer)

where is my mistake???

## .py code

```
      from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic,QtCore, QtGui
      from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
      
      import pyqtgraph as pg
      import sys  
      
      class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
      
          def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
              super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
              #Load the UI Page
              uic.loadUi('teeeeest.ui', self)
              self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_plot)
              
          def show_plot(self):
               ############################################ this code draws in the specified location without any problem:
               # self.graphics_View_widget.clear() 
               # pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
               # h=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
               # t=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
               # self.graphics_View_widget.plot(h, t, pen=(0,0,255))
      
      
               ############################################ this code draws a new window (instead of specified location in qt designer)
                 self.graphics_View_widget.clear()  
                 h=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                 t=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
                 xDict=dict(enumerate(t))
                 xValue=list(xDict.keys())
                 self.graphics_View_widget= pg.GraphicsWindow()
                 bottomAxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
                 pp=self.graphics_View_widget.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': bottomAxis},name='h')
                 xtickts=[xDict.items()]
                 bottomAxis.setTicks(xtickts)
                 pp.plot(xValue,h)
      
      if __name__ == '__main__':      
          app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
          main = MainWindow()
          main.show()
          sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: qt designer ui]
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Well, it makes sense: you're creating a new widget, Qt (or python for what matters) has no way to know that you want to replace the existing one. Just remove the line in which you overwrite `self.graphics_View_widget`.

Comment: remove `self.graphics_View_widget= pg.GraphicsWindow()`

Comment: @eyllanesc when i remove that line, error  says (NameError: addPlot) and the code can not draw

Comment: @michaelbiehn please provide a [mre] (.ui and .py)

Comment: @eyllanesc i add the exact code and update the question.is there anything else that i should share? if there is please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is soloution:

1. add a Qgraphicsview( name it widget_test)

2.promote class name=GraphicsLayoutWidget --- header name=pyqtgraph

```
             h=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
             t=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
             xDict=dict(enumerate(t))
             xValue=list(xDict.keys())
             bottomAxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
             pp=self.widget_test.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': bottomAxis},name='h')
             xtickts=[xDict.items()]
             bottomAxis.setTicks(xtickts)
             pp.plot(xValue,h)
```

and now you have pyqtgraph with string x axis inside of your form

good luck